# How to write the cross-project prediction algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am new in machine learning and now I am facing an issue. I have 7 projects I would like to predict whether a pull request would be rejected or not (Yes or No). And I would like to build a prediction model by using data from 6 projects as source project and predict the rejection of the pull request in the seventh project as a target project. Can someone tell me how can I structure my algorithm in `Scikit-learn`?
Hope that my question is clear.

Thanks